# jQuery else block

Tags: jquery

I have problem with the `else` block. The `if` block works well - when the value of `#finish_day` is less then `4`, the options values in `#get_car` and `#return_car` (select) are the same.

I can change the option in `#get_car` and in `#return_car` automatically and only one is active (the same as in `#get_car`).

Unfortunately when value in `#finish_day` is greater then `4` (`else` block) I can't activate options in `#return_car` - still only one option is active and rest is disabled.

This is my code:

```
if ( $("#finish_day").val() < 4 ) {
   $('#get_car, #return_car').not(this)
       .children('option[value=' + this.value + ']')
       .attr('selected', true)
       .siblings().attr('disabled', true);
} else {
      $('#get_car, #return_car').attr('selected', false);
}
```

I don't know what's wrong? I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Can you please add your HTML to your question ...  or even better create a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but you never try to **enable** the elements you **disabled**. You need something like `$('#get_car, #return_car').children().prop('disabled', false)`, but it would be much easier to help you if you'd provide your markup and a demo.

Comment: You also applying `selected` to the select, not its options as you would with $('#get_car, #return_car').children().prop('selected', false);

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/amarcinkowski/W7NHK/1/ my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 else {
     $('#get_car > option, #return_car > option').prop('disabled', false)
 }
```

Comment: it activate the #return_car list, but it clear #get_car. And after that the both option list are cleared

Comment: now it's ok :) there is one more problem i noticed - when i change values in #return_car and #get_car and after that I change the value in #finish_day back to value lesser than 4 the options in #get_car didn't change and are all visible